# Drawing in JScript on Windows CE

Tags: javascript, drawing, internet-explorer-6, windows-ce, jscript

We are working with Windows CE 5, and the Mobile Internet Explorer 6 which supports JScript 5.6 (should be equal to JavaScript 1.5).

Now we want to draw some lines.
VML seems not supported and i tried out some drawing librries like Raphael, flotr, jsdraw2d but none of them seem to work.

Has anyone a suggestion for drawing with Windows CE Mobile Internet Explorer in CE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i found a library that works with the ocnfiguration, it´s called: wz_jsgraphics.js
from
http://www.c-point.com/javascript_vector_draw.htm

Comment: Superb - just what I was looking for! :)